# How can I use another user's display

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm using xdotool in a SSH connection logged in as root, I'm setting `DISPLAY=":0.0"` which is what `echo $DISPLAY` on the logged user says. But I get a error unless I `su` to the other user:

```
root@sb:~# export DISPLAY=":0.0"
root@sb:~# xdotool getactivewindow
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

```
geerm@sb:~$ export DISPLAY=":0.0"
geerm@sb:~$ xdotool getactivewindow
41943046
```

Is this even possible? If so, what do I need to change to use the logged in user's session?

Comment: If you've any further bugs or `Segmentation fault`s, you should either check or report them at [xdotool GitHub](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, most X servers disallow other users displaying to each other's screens. If you want to disable this protection, you might be able to using [xhost](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xhost.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
export DISPLAY=his_xserver_ip:0.0
```

and probably you need to add the IP allowed to connect to his xserver to his xhosts thru xhost +ip_to_connnect_from

http://www.xfree86.org/current/X.7.html

Comment: what if it's the same host, just another user.

Comment: same host as in same X-server? you share the same screen with the other guy?

Comment: i'm both, i'm trying to use a script that runs as root that keeps google chrome open, if it's not, i want to open it, the logged in user is A, and the script runs as root, I understand i can sudo -u A , just trying to avoid it